# I have a solar panel with below specifications. I have some questions

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller, specifications

[image]

1. As in picture Vmp = 17.40V and Imp = 0.58A implies Power =
   17.40*0.58 ≈ 10W.

Does it provide 0.833A (10/12) at 12 volts?

2. What does "Max. System Voltage 800VDC" mean in the picture ?

Comment: The [TSI composite](https://www.pmodwrc.ch/en/research-development/solar-physics/tsi-composite/) illustrates what takes place before entering the Earth's atmosphere. The Bond albedo is about 30%, so the resulting isolation at the Earth's surface, at the equator at noon, is about \$1000\:\frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}^2}\$. That's where the test conditions listed come from. It's all great if you live on the equator, have clear skies at noon, and are calibrating your panel there and then. Otherwise? Not so much. None of the specifications mean anything much anywhere/anywhen else. They need derating.

Comment: No. It produces 0.58A at 17V and 0.66A at 0V so it produces somewhere in between them at 12V.

Comment: Look up the "I/V curve of a solar panel"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As in picture Vmp = 17.40V and Imp = 0.58A implies Power = 17.40*0.58 ≈ 10W.
> So does it provide 0.833A (10/12) at 12 Volt ?

Absolutely not. You'll notice it will only deliver 0.66A into a short circuit under rated conditions. So if you load the output to 12 V, you'll get significantly less than 12 * 0.66 = 7.9 watts.

Bear in mind that the 'rated' conditions are just that, rated. You're unlikely to see that much illumination consistently at the best of times. The real output will be much less than this.

You are told that the maximum output is when the panel is delivering 17.4 volts. If you want the best output power, load it with a MPPT converter, and convert whatever voltage it's delivering at the maximum output power to your needed 12 V.

> What is Max. System Voltage 800VDC Mean in the picture ?

These panels are often connected in series, to minimise the amount of copper wire needed for efficient connection to the load. Connect enough in series, and you get some very high voltages build up along the string. This panel's insulation is being claimed to withstand 800 V to ground. I'm not sure I'd ever run domestic panels at such a high voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The output power of 10W is at MPP (Maximum Power Point).
This won't be the power delivered when the panel voltage is 12V.
To obtain the maximum power of 10W with an output voltage of 12V, use a suitable DC/DC converter with an output voltage of 12V.
With this, the panel delivers 10W and you have 12V DC output.

Comment: Only when "suitable" means "having MPPT capabilities". A mere DC/DC converter with its output set to 12V will not make the panel operate at its MPP; it will most likely pull its input to 12V and deliver quite a bit less than 10W.